# Comparadores do JavaScript - [ajuda]

Tags: javascript

**Prezados, boa tarde!**

*Poderiam me auxiliar com o código JS abaixo, estou encontrando algumas dificuldades, mas não consigo identificar direito o que poderia ser ajustado.*

*"Função que recebe dois elementos e retorna uma mensagem dizendo se eles são estritamente iguais,*
*equivalentes ou diferentes, com o seu tipo entre parênteses logo após o valor."*

**Entrada**

```
comparadorBasico(3,3)
comparadorBasico()               ---- Não passou nessa.
comparadorBasico("ABC","ABC")    ---- Não passou nessa.
comparadorBasico(3,"3")
comparadorBasico(null)
comparadorBasico(1,2)
comparadorBasico("1",2)          ---- Não passou nessa.
```

**Saída esperada das que não passaram**

```
Elemento undefined (undefined) é estritamente igual ao elemento undefined (undefined)
Elemento 1 (string) é diferente do elemento 2 (number)
Elemento 1 (string) é diferente do elemento 2 (number)
```

**Meu código até agora:**

```
function comparadorBasico(elemento1, elemento2) {
    if (elemento1 === elemento2){
        return ('Elemento ' + elemento1 + ' ' + '(number)' + ' é estritamente igual ao elemento ' + elemento2 + ' ' + '(number)')
    }

    else if (elemento1 != elemento2){
        return ('Elemento ' + elemento1 + ' (string)' + ' é diferente do elemento ' + elemento2 + ' (number)')
    }
    else if (elemento1 = elemento2){
        return ('Elemento ' + elemento1 + ' (number)' + ' é equivalente ao elemento ' + elemento2 + ' (string)')
    }
    else if (elemento1 === elemento2){
        return ('Elemento ' + null +' (object)' + ' é equivalente ao elemento ' + elemento2 + ' (undefined)')
    }
 }
```

*Qualquer ajuda é válida, agradeço! :)*

Comment: `comparadorBasico("ABC","ABC")    ---- Não passou nessa.` Certeza disso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu vi alguns pontos no seu código que necessitariam serem revistos. Primeiramente, no terceiro if, você colocou apenas um sinal de igual, nesse caso vc está atribuindo o valor do elemento2 ao elemento1, ao invés de estar comparando. O correto seria:

```
else if (elemento1 == elemento2){
   return ('Elemento ' + elemento1 + ' (number)' + ' é equivalente ao elemento ' + elemento2 + ' (string)')
}
```

Outra questão é que o último IF nunca será atingido, pois ele é o mesmo que o primeiro, portanto é um código desnecessário, poderia apagá-lo.

Eu fiz uma versão do código e gostaria de compartilhá-lo com você, veja se concorda comigo e se dará certo:

```
function comparadorBasico(elemento1, elemento2) {
  let comparador;
  if (elemento1 === elemento2) {
    comparador = 'estritamente igual';
  } else if (elemento1 == elemento2) {
    comparador = 'equivalente'
  } else {
    comparador = 'diferente';
  }
  return `Elemento ${elemento1} (${typeof elemento1}) é ${comparador} ao elemento ${elemento2} (${typeof elemento2})`
}
```

Primeiramente, eu criei uma variável para armazenar qual é a relação de comparação entre os dois elementos, para evitar ficar retornando a mensagem toda hora. Depois faço 3 comparações: comparo se são do mesmo tipo e do mesmo valor ("==="), depois comparo se são iguais porém de tipos diferentes ("=="), e se não der certo nenhuma opção anteriormente, significa que são diferentes. Por fim monto a mensagem de retorno.

Há! Uma dica! Você pode utilizar `typeof nomeVariavel` para saber qual é o tipo dela.

Answer (score 1):

Tenho um exercícios referente essa sua duvida, e fiz o código dessa forma.

function comparadorBasico(elemento1, elemento2) {

```
if (elemento1 === elemento2) {
   console.log("Elemento",+elemento1, typeof elemento1+ " é estritamente igual ao elemento", +elemento2, typeof elemento2)
  }else if(elemento1 !== elemento2){
    console.log("Elemento",+elemento1, typeof elemento1+ " é diferente igual ao elemento",+elemento2, typeof elemento2)
  }else{
    console.log("Elemento",elemento1, typeof elemento1+ " é equivalente ao elemento",+elemento2, typeof elemento2)
  }
```

}

comparadorBasico(2,2)
Elemento2number é estritamente igual ao elemento2number